# How to type ( without turn into ( ) in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

How to type a ( without turn into ( ) in RStudio script editor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences -> Code Editing` and remove the check-mark at `Insert matching parens/quotes`.

Answer (score 0):

In your menu bar, go in Tools/Options and then click on "Insert matchin parnes/quotes".

[image]